# Emacs: fastest way to open a file whose location is not known

Tags: emacs

What is the easiest way to open a txt file whose path has to be found using the shell find command?

For example, let say I want to open a file that I know is (uniquely) named *example.txt* and which I know is "somewhere I can find it using the shell *find* command".

What I do currently is this:

I do *C-u* (universal-argument) then *M-!* (shell command)

I then enter the *find*, for example:

```
find . -iname "example.txt"
```

Then the full path (which I didn't know previously) appears in the buffer, I cut it, then I hit *C-x C-f*, I delete what written by default and then paste what I cut before.

This seems a bit long and requires quite a few keystrokes, cut'n'pasting etc.

Is there an easiest way to do the same (without writing a new custom Emacs command)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using only built-in functionality, I would:

- Go to a shell buffer: <kbd>M-x shell</kbd>
- Run my find command.
- Move the cursor up so that it's on top of the file path that was found.
- Run the `find-file-at-point` command: <kbd>M-x ffap</kbd>.

I use `find-file-at-point` often enough that I have it bound to a dedicated key, <kbd>s-\</kbd> (super-backslash).

Answer (score 10):

```
M-x find-name-dired
```

Enter the dir (defaults to current) and filename (shell globs work too) and you'll get a virtual dired buffer with the results.  Go the file you want and hit '`a`'

Answer (score 6):

Try out [ifind.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind.el)

```
M-x ifind /some/starting/point/example.txt
```

Will search for `example.txt` in directories below `/some/starting/point`.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x locate` is the fastest way to find and open a file, esp. if you know the exact filename, in emacs.

Answer (score 2):

If your folder constitutes a "project" - something under a version control or having a root folder marker such as project.el, .dir-locals.el, etc, you can use the [find-file-in-project](http://github.com/bbatsov/find-file-in-project), which in my opinion is an excellent solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at [LocateFilesAnywhere](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere)

I happen to use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `anything-locate`

Answer (score 1):

In **Icicles** you can find files by matching not just the relative file name but any parts of the path.  You can use substring, regexp, and fuzzy matching.  You can AND together multiple search patterns (progressive completion).  See multi-command `icicle-locate-file`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd>

then you have a dired buffer showing your files returned by find. You can use classic dired command to open/move/rename... files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that globalff is not mentioned as one of the viable option. Sure it requires locate command but its quite fast and useful when you can't recall the exact  name.